# How much xp do I need to level up?

Tags: pokemon-go

How much XP is needed to level up to each level in Pokemon Go?

I'd like to know how much harder it will get to level up to higher levels.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept your answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*[Source](http://serebii.net/pokemongo/trainer.shtml)*

The table below shows the xp needed to get to the next level at any given level. As well as the total xp needed to get to the next level from any given level.

For example at level 3, you will need 3k xp to get to level 4 which is a total of 6k xp (from level 1 you will need 6k xp to get to level 4).

```
+-------+--------+--------------+
| Level | XP (k) | Total XP (k) |
+-------+--------+--------------+
|     1 |      1 |            1 |
|     2 |      2 |            3 |
|     3 |      3 |            6 |
|     4 |      4 |           10 |
|     5 |      5 |           15 |
|     6 |      6 |           21 |
|     7 |      7 |           28 |
|     8 |      8 |           36 |
|     9 |      9 |           45 |
|    10 |     10 |           55 |
|    11 |     10 |           65 |
|    12 |     10 |           75 |
|    13 |     10 |           85 |
|    14 |     15 |          100 |
|    15 |     20 |          120 |
|    16 |     20 |          140 |
|    17 |     20 |          160 |
|    18 |     25 |          185 |
|    19 |     25 |          210 |
|    20 |     50 |          260 |
|    21 |     75 |          335 |
|    22 |    100 |          435 |
|    23 |    125 |          560 |
|    24 |    150 |          710 |
|    25 |    190 |          900 |
|    26 |    200 |         1100 |
|    27 |    250 |         1350 |
|    28 |    300 |         1650 |
|    29 |    350 |         2000 |
|    30 |    500 |         2500 |
|    31 |    500 |         3000 |
|    32 |    750 |         3750 |
|    33 |   1000 |         4750 |
|    34 |   1250 |         6000 |
|    35 |   1500 |         7500 |
|    36 |   2000 |         9500 |
|    37 |   2500 |        12000 |
|    38 |   3000 |        15000 |
|    39 |   5000 |        20000 |
|    40 |    MAX |          MAX |
+-------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Does this mean you need 2000 times the amount of XP to get to level 30, than you do to get to level 1?

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox Yes, so to go from level 29  to 30 you'd have to walk 5,000km while breeding eggs. 25.000km to get from 1 to 30. :) It's a free to play game, there's definitely *some* grinding involved.

Comment: @Mario the k stands for thousand as in thousand xp points. George from the start you'd need 2500000 xp to get to level 30. But from level 29 you only need 500000 xp

Comment: @Aequitas Exactly. You need 500,000xp and you'll get 1,000 xp from a 10km egg, so you'll need 500 eggs. 500 * 10km = 5,000km

Comment: There's more (and easier) ways to get XP than just through eggs, @Mario

Comment: This table is off-by-one - you start at level one but the table shows it needs 1k EXP just to get there. It takes 2mil EXP to get to Level 30 from zero.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I can see why you misread it. How I meant is that at level 1, you need 1 k xp to level up to the next level.

Comment: I'd say that the "Total XP" column is misleading still - I mean, if I look at the row labelled Lv20, it seems to say 260k is the total, but at that point it's 210k...

Comment: One interesting thing is that the required XP to reach a level is exponential in the level number (pretty accurately for the higher levels, not so much for the lower levels). So even if you could double your XP, it would only raise you approximately 3 levels. Puts the whole lucky egg thing in perspective.